# Qooxdoo contrib library is not being included

Tags: user-interface, web-applications, qooxdoo

Qooxdoo seems to be exactly what I want to develop my web app, but I'm running into problems trying to include a contrib library into my project. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Relevant part of my config.json:

```
"libraries" : 
  {
    "library" :
    [
      {
        "manifest" : "contrib://SkeletonApplication/trunk/Manifest.json"
      },
      {
        "mainfest" : "contrib://CollapsablePanel/trunk/Manifest.json",
        "uri" : "../contrib/CollapsablePanel/trunk"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I've tried with and without the uri entry; using contrib://, relative and absolute paths for the manifest and uri entries.

As far as I can tell, 'generate.py source-all -w' isn't even looking for the contrib library: there are a whole lot of "- including " lines output but nothing at all about "contrib".

I'm using Qooxdoo 1.3 locally on my Linux box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file wasn't highlighted and I didn't realise it was commented out.

Comment: I have not used the Collapsable Panel contribution. Good choice on qooxdoo!